# How do I set the width of my label to be centered over the chart on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, canvas

I have the following html. I would like the label (Open/Resolved Issues (All Teams) to be centered above my chart (which is rendered in the canvas). I have tried it without the span, and with the span tag, nothing changes. I am using bootstrap and chart.js if that matters.

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1"><p></p></div>
      <div class="border col-xs-4">
          <label class="graph_caption" for="open_resolved_chart">
              <span class="center full">Open/Resolved Issues (All Teams)</span><br />
              <canvas id="open_resolved_chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
          </label>
          <br>
          <span id="open_resolved_chart_legend"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"><p></p></div>
      <div class="border col-xs-4">
          <label class="graph_caption" for="open_resolved_chart_agg">
              <span class="center full">Open/Resolved Issues (Agg Team)</span><br />
              <canvas id="open_resolved_chart_agg" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
          </label>
          <br>
          <span id="open_resolved_chart_agg_legend"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
```

css contents:

```
.graph_caption {
    text-size: 1.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.center
{
    text-align: center;
}
.full
{
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You will probably get more responses if you also provide a link to a jsfiddle showing the example you can't get working with chart.js and bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Span elements are inline, not block elements, which means they don't take up the entire width. You could add display: block to full, or change it to a div element.

Also, bootstrap provides a text-center class that you should be using in lieu of custom css classes (.center)